# Отправка сообщений в канал телеграмм [не бот]

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Цель - создать файл и повесить его на крон, для запуска по таймеру.
Код парсит инфу с ресурса, кладет ее в массив и должен постить 1 элемент.

Тут начинается магия.

Сообщение в ТГ должно отправляться от лица админа\группы (не знаю как правильно), но не ботом.

Далее часть кода:

```
client = TelegramClient('some_name', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()
```

После этого этапа в консоль падает запрос на ввод номера и кода для авторизации.
Проблема том, что он это требует на постоянной основе, а не 1 раз. Соответственно как пропустить эту проверку?

Аккаунт рабочий - личный.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того чтобы избежать постоянной проверки номера и кода авторизации при каждом запуске, можно создать сессию для клиента `TelegramClient`. Это позволит сохранить данные авторизации для дальнейшего использования.

Пример кода:

```py
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient

sessionname = 'sessionname'  # Имя для вашей сессии, может быть любым

apiid = 'yourapiid'  # Ваш API ID
apihash = 'yourapihash'  # Ваш API Hash

client = TelegramClient(sessionname, apiid, apihash)
client.start()

channelusername = 'yourchannelusername'  # Имя вашего канала начинается с @

message = 'Сообщение, которое нужно отправить'
client.sendmessage(channelusername, message)

client.disconnect()
```

В этом примере мы создаем объект `TelegramClient` и инициализируем его с помощью метода `start()`. После этого мы можем использовать метод `sendmessage()` для отправки сообщения через бота.

Убедись, что ты правильно указали `apiid`, `apihash` и имя своего канала `(@yourchannelusername)`. Также не забудьте установить библиотеку `telethon`, если еще не сделали этого:

```
pip install telethon
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. 
Уже делал подобную вещь. 

Проблема при такой реализации:
При первом запуске требует ввод телефона
Далее код полученный этим телефоном
Далее скрипт отрабатывает 1 раз. 

Результат: 
Меня выкинуло со всех связанных с этим аккаунтом устройств.
Второй запуск приложения, также требует телефона и кода (а с устройств меня уже выкинуло).

В какой-то момент просто не мог зайтиа на аккаунт, потому что мой пароль "устарел" на протяжении суток. Т.е. приходит код на авторизацию, и он сразу устарел.

Решил проблема все таки с помощью создания бота.